# Why can't i get the value of the scrollWidth property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, gsap

i'm a student who's learning a little about the gsap library to make some animation for my portfolio project. It's my first time using it and i don't really have strong Javascript basics...

I want to re-create something like this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/LilianChesneau/pen/VwGpENv) which I made from some online tutorials. It's fully working in CodePen and also in a basic html/css/js repertory but not in my Vue template.

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
const images = gsap.utils.toArray("img");
const loader = document.querySelector(".loader--text");
const updateProgress = (instance) =>
  (loader.textContent = `${Math.round(
    (instance.progressedCount * 100) / images.length
  )}%`);
const showDemo = () => {
  document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
  document.scrollingElement.scrollTo(0, 0);
  gsap.to(document.querySelector(".loader"), {
    autoAlpha: 0
  });
  gsap.utils.toArray("section").forEach((section, index) => {
    const w = section.querySelector(".oui");
    const [x, xEnd] =
      index % 2
        ? ["100%", (w.scrollWidth - section.offsetWidth) * -1]
        : [w.scrollWidth * -1, 0];
    gsap.fromTo(
      w,
      {
        x
      },
      {
        x: xEnd,
        scrollTrigger: {
          trigger: section,
          scrub: 0.5
        }
      }
    );
  });
};
imagesLoaded(images).on("progress", updateProgress).on("always", showDemo);
```

The error message is : "*Cannot read properties of null (reading 'scrollWidth')*"

You can download my vue project [here](https://filesender.renater.fr/?s=download&token=ef55e02b-839c-44bf-a44b-719920b4006a)

I tried to reinstall the needed plugins and to search for people with the same issues but i can't really find why I can't get it to work with Vue. I also found some article which could refer to the fact that I'm trying to access a class that hasn't appeared yet but I don't quite understand this point.

Comment: Where's your *Vue* code?

Comment: Everything needed for the page is in the publication. The other pages (which do not have this animation) work normally. Let me know if it's not enought.

Comment: I was unable to reproduce.  The exact code works ok when pasted into this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-dewdney-cqlkhf?file=/src/App.vue).  I would try maybe reinstalling your dependencies: delete `node_modules` folder, delete `package-lock.json`, then run `npm install` and try running again after that

Comment: I tried, everything seems to be in place every time but it's always the same: the code works well everywhere but I can't seem to be able to make it work in my template...

Comment: The error suggests you are trying the read a property (scrollWidth) of a null object (w). so you problem might be with `const w = section.querySelector(".oui");`. try loggin out the value of w and make sure it is what you expect.